# Excel - Count unique values on multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula

My head is just sort of spinning on this and the solution examples.  Can someone please provided a solution for this specific issue?  Once I see it for what I need then it clicks on how to use elsewhere with different variables.  Learning disorder of sorts.  Thank you.

```
A       B       C        D           E
First   Last    Account Transaction  Status
Frank   Tomas   101     ACH          Fraud
Dillon  Krege   105     CC-DC   
Joann   Krimble 103     ACH 
Frank   Tomas   101     Wire    
Clint   Edwards 102     ACH         Fraud
Joann   Krimble 103     CC-DC       Fraud
Joann   Krimble 103     ACH
```

Unique Account (column C) using Transaction (column D) of "ACH" and coded as Status (column E) of "Fraud"?

There are 3000+ rows in this sheet, if that makes a difference.  Pivot table not an option, which I could have done quickly.

Comment: ugghhh.  The formatting in the box didn't work.  Let me take a pic

Comment: no Please leave it as text I have fixed it.

Comment: Please roll back the edit to put the text back in.  We cannot copy paste a photo.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((D2:D8="ACH")*(E2:E8="FRAUD"))/(COUNTIFS(C:C,C2:C8,D:D,"ACH",E:E,"FRAUD")+(D2:D8<>"ACH")+(E2:E8<>"FRAUD")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same method as the response from [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) but incorporates dynamic column length.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((D$2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))=H2)*(E$2:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))=I2))/
            (COUNTIFS(C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C:C)), C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C:C)),
                      D$2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99, C:C)), H2, E$2:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, C:C)), I2)+
            (D$2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))<>H2)+(E$2:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))<>I2)))
```

This formula's dynamic column length does depend on the accounts being true numbers.

[image]